# Is there any user defined / customized FORMAT and TRY_CAST?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with SQL stored procedures. Below FORMAT and TRY_CAST getting this error.

> 'TRY_CAST' is not a recognized built-in function name.

```
SELECT FORMAT(TRY_CAST(MYDATE AS INT),'00/00/0000')
```

So I want to use user defined FORMAT and TRY_CAST functions. But don't have any idea about these function. is there any existing user defined function instead of FORMAT and TRY_CAST.

EDIT (from comment):

I am using 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) Apr 2 2010 15:48:46 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor) ' this version. I want to convert 'ddmmyyyy' format to 'dd/mm/yyyy' this. I can done with just using string manipulation. but I want some decent code. so I try this FORMAT and TRY_CAST.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  And what do you expect getting a date as an int?  Sample data and desired results would probably be a better format for a question.

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): _"APPLIES TO: SQL Server (starting with 2012)"_. You're probably on pre-2012? Why are you asking about user-defined variations of these functions? What have you tried?

Comment: Check the `print @@version` output, most probably it will tell you that your SQL Server is earlier than 2012.

Comment: And please stop pity-upvoting zero-research questions.

Comment: `TRY_CAST` and `FORMAT` work on all supported SQL Server versions, ie 2012+. In those versions, if you want to format a date just use `FORMAT(mydate,...)` with the format string and culture you want, eg `FORMAT(mydate,'dd/MM/yyyy')` or `FORMAT(myDate,'d','en-US')`. Even in a supported version those multiple casts and formats will probably result in unexpected results

Comment: @GordonLinoff and other bro's.. I am using 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
 Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)
' this version. I want to convert 'ddmmyyyy' format to 'dd/mm/yyyy' this. I can done with just using string manipulation. but I want some decent code. so I try this FORMAT and TRY_CAST.

Comment: If your users really want something other than [provided set of formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles) then you might consider formatting the dates in the UI, after you get them out of the database.

Comment: @Crowcoder given data is varchar datatype. so there is two ways only string manipulation or above function.

Comment: WARNING - NO ONE should be using 2008 RTM at this late date. That is dangerously obsolete and unsupported.

Comment: @ArulmuruganK I see, it was not clear that your date was not a date. You could always cast it to a date then convert it back with the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert "ddmmyyyy format to dd/mm/yyyy", just use string functions:

```
select stuff(stuff(my_date, 5, '/'), 3, '/')
```

The functions you want to use are not supported in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, its pretty and its woking.  I have do little correction to avoid syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any existing user defined function instead of FORMAT and
>   TRY_CAST.

No, by definition there are no existing user defined functions on your SQL Server until you create them.  That is what the "user defined" bit means.